# Is it possible to use this gltf of a tree point cloud that has the following errors

Tags: textures, gltf

I downloaded a tree point cloud from sketchfab but once I ran it through the Khronos gltf validator, it returned the following errors.

I tried adding textures to this model in blender but did not see any change. Is it possible to use this model or do I need to find another/make my own point cloud?

The Khronos Group
glTF Validator
Select glTF or GLB asset or drop it here.

The asset contains errors.

```
> Alternate glTF validation methods available:
> Command-Line | NPM | VS Code Extension
> Validation is performed locally in your browser. Submitted assets are not uploaded.
> 
> {
>     "uri": "scene.gltf",
>     "mimeType": "model/gltf+json",
>     "validatorVersion": "2.0.0-dev.3.8",
>     "validatedAt": "2023-03-21T01:10:45.711Z",
>     "issues": {
>         "numErrors": 1,
>         "numWarnings": 0,
>         "numInfos": 0,
>         "numHints": 0,
>         "messages": [
>             {
>                 "code": "IO_ERROR",
>                 "message": "Resource not found (scene.bin).",
>                 "severity": 0,
>                 "pointer": "/buffers/0/uri"
>             }
>         ],
>         "truncated": false
>     },
>     "info": {
>         "version": "2.0",
>         "generator": "Sketchfab-13.3.0",
>         "extensionsUsed": [
>             "KHR_materials_unlit"
>         ],
>         "resources": [
>             {
>                 "pointer": "/buffers/0",
>                 "mimeType": "application/gltf-buffer",
>                 "storage": "external",
>                 "uri": "scene.bin"
>             }
>         ],
>         "animationCount": 0,
>         "materialCount": 1,
>         "hasMorphTargets": false,
>         "hasSkins": false,
>         "hasTextures": false,
>         "hasDefaultScene": true,
>         "drawCallCount": 8,
>         "totalVertexCount": 70991,
>         "totalTriangleCount": 0,
>         "maxUVs": 0,
>         "maxInfluences": 0,
>         "maxAttributes": 2
>     }
> }
```

What I did:

Downloaded tree point cloud from sketchfab [(here is the page)](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/tree63-pointcloud-080483a68630459b87ac4cb97bf062c3)

What I expected:

Blender + Unity - expected to see a material on the tree. It shows up as invisible

[gltf_error_blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPzuQ.jpg)

EDIT
Thanks to @Don's excellent tip, ran it through [gltf.report](https://gltf.report/) and got the following result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeAqi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error ("Resource not found (scene.bin)") suggests that the *validation software* did not have access to the .bin file containing the mesh data. You can probably fix that by dragging the whole folder into the validator, including the .bin file, but I wouldn't worry too much about validating the file if it appears correctly in online viewers (e.g. https://gltf.report/), and this model does appear OK.

The larger problems here are:

1. The default scale of the model is huge, and the default position is very far from 0,0,0. Both of these things make the model difficult to bring into the viewport in Blender.
2. The model is a point cloud, and has no UVs, so you won't be able to add textures to it in Blender. The color information is in vertex colors.

> EDIT: Further discussion in [mrdoob/three.js#25697](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/25697), including ways to convert this model to vertex colors.

Comment: Hi Don, Thanks for providing such a detailed response. My plan is to 1. convert this model to vertex colors so I can see it when I bring into Blender. Then 2. scale it down and reset the origin to 0,0,0. I tried your [script](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/25697) but got the following error { message: "Cannot read properties of null…" ,line: 9 ,column: 3 }
message: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getTexCoord')"
line: 9
column: 3

Comment: Blender doesn't require the vertex colors for a point cloud I think, that's just three.js. Blender is only struggling with the scale and origin here. My script is written with the assumption that you're processing a textured mesh and baking the texture's data into vertex colors. The error suggests this new model does not have a texture. For more help adapting the script to a different model, could you open a Discussion thread at https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/discussions? Thanks!